# Soft brake pedal goes to floor after changing brakes and rotor

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting, bleeding

I had someone change my brake pads and rotor. However now that they have I have no working brakes. I hear weird noise from car brakes. The  brake light is on. We have filled brake fluid (since it was almost empty). He supposedly bled the brakes.

I really need car for work. I almost ran someone over because it wouldn't stop.

Comment: Who is "someone" in this case?  A mechanic at a shop or just someone you know?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you try pumping the brakes while vehicle was stopped? When brakes are changed, it can leave the caliper fully retracted and won't push out without several pumps of the brakes. I'm going on the premise the person who did the work didn't actually bleed the brakes. Bleeding the brakes isn't required when brakes are replaced.

Comment: Take it back and tell them to fix it as someone didn't do their job right.